# Selecting Alias From a View in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, view, alias

How can I select a column from a view that has been created with an alias? What is the best way to go about retrieving this data?

This is the view:

```
SELECT
    s.Code, s.[DATE], s.[Name], s.[Team],
    CASE
       WHEN MONTH(s.[DATE]) = MONTH(getdate()) 
            AND YEAR(s.[DATE]) = YEAR(getdate())
          THEN SUM(isnull(f.figure, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY s.[Name], MONTH(s.[DATE])) 
          ELSE 0
    END AS 'Month To Date'
FROM
    Salesperson s
LEFT JOIN 
    Figure f ON s.Code = f.Salesperson
```

I want to select the value for the month to date in another query but it obviously errors. What is the best way around this?

Comment: What will be the error you got.

Comment: embrace column name in square brackets, like [Month To Date] while selecting from the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. There was an error before but it was something unrelated. Simply just use the alias name and that works